# Let $Y_n,X_n$ be a sequence of r.v. Does $\sup_z \Big|P(Y_n<z\ |\ X_n) - \Phi(z)\Big|\rightarrow_p0 \implies \{Y_n|X_n=x_n\}\xrightarrow[]{d}N(0,1)?$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Y_n,X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Does $\sup_z \Big|P(Y_n<z\ |\ X_n) - \Phi(z)\Big|\xrightarrow[]{p}0$ implies $\{Y_n|X_n=x_n\}\xrightarrow[]{d}N(0,1)?$ where $x_n$ is any sequence of real numbers within the support of $X_n$. Note that $P(Y_n<z\ |\ X_n)$ is a random variable.

By asymptotic equivalence, the above implies for all value of $z$, $P(Y_n<z\ |\ X_n)\xrightarrow[]{d}\Phi(z)$ which implies $P(Y_n<z\ |\ X_n)\xrightarrow[]{p}\Phi(z)$ for all $z$. This is as far as I could go.

This question is closely related to this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125675/convergence-of-conditional-probability-when-sequences-of-random-variables-conver).

Comment: What is $\Phi$ in this problem? Is it the cdf of the normal distribution?

Comment: Yes, $\Phi$ is the normal CDF.

Comment: What is the definition of $(Y_n\mid X_n)\stackrel{d}\to\mathcal{N}(0,1)$? You are considering the limit of random distributions (i.e., random variables taking values in the space of probability distributions), and so, you would want to specify the mode under which the limit is taken.

Comment: $Y_n|X_n\xrightarrow[]{d}N(0,1)$ means $Y_n|X_n$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable.

Comment: It is like 'a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers' versus 'a sequence $(X_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables'. If $(\mu_n)$ is a sequence of probability distributions, then we can certainly discuss the convergence in distribution of $(\mu_n)$. But what you have here is a sequence of 'random probability distributions', or equivalently, probability-distribution-valued random variables. So you need to clarify what it means by the limit of it. For example, we can discuss something like $$(Y_n\mid X_n)\xrightarrow{\text{in distribution}}\mathcal{N}(0,1) \quad\text{in probability.}$$

Comment: I dont understand your question completely but $\xrightarrow[]{p}$ means convergence in probability and $\xrightarrow[]{d}$ means c onvergence in distribution (or in law). In particular, $(Y_n|X_n)\xrightarrow[]{d} N(0,1)$ means $F_{Y_n|X_n}(z)\rightarrow \Phi(z)$ for all $z$.

Comment: Using the notation you mentioned, what I mean is that $F_{Y_n\mid X_n}(\cdot)$ is a *random function*, i.e., you are dealing with the convergence of some random variables. So it should be made clear as to what $F_{Y_n\mid X_n}\to\Phi$ means.

Comment: $F_{Y_n|X_n}(z)$ is no longer random...

Comment: Then would you clarify what it means by $F_{Y_n\mid X_n}$? I thought you are considering the function $$F_{Y_n\mid X_n}(z)=\mathbf{P}(Y_n\leq z\mid X_n),$$ which is random.

Comment: The CDF of $Y_n|X_n$?

Comment: Somewhat curious - can we just let $Z_n = Y_n | X_n$?

Comment: $P(Y_n<z\ \mid X_n)$ may be a random variable (as it is a function of $X_n$) but I am not sure $Y_n \mid X_n$ is

Comment: Please give a mathematical definition of your "CDF of $(Y_n\mid X_n)$". You seem to be already understanding that the conditional CDF, $\mathbf{P}(Y_n\leq z\mid X_n)$, is *random* (i.e., a random element in the space of probability distributions). So I am not sure what is preventing you from getting to the idea that a distribution itself can be random and that random distributions need to be treated in the same way you deal with the limit of random variables.

Comment: Why do you think $Y_n | X_n$ might not be random?

Comment: Hi Sangchul. Please this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution

Comment: Please check the section ['Measure-theoretic formulation' in your link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation). The conditional probability distribution of $Y_n$ given $X_n$ (or more precisely, the sigma-algebra $\sigma(X_n)$ generated by $X_n$) is a random distribution (or equivalently, a measurable function from $\Omega\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: I think $Y_n \mid X_n$ may not be well defined at all.  For example $(Y_n \mid X_n) \le z$ looks like an event, but I doubt there is a probability space that has it as an event and I do not see whether   $P\big ( (Y_n \mid X_n) \le z\big)$ is supposed to be a numerical value or a random variable or something else

Comment: Apologies. I see where the confusion comes from. I think writting $Y_n|X_n = x_n\xrightarrow[]{d}N(0,1)$ might clear the confusion?

Comment: Referring to your last formulation, you should specify I think what is $x_n$ with $x$ small. Maybe any sequence of real numbers going to infinity?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, I've put that it.

Comment: Since the notion of $F_{Y_n\mid X_n=x}$ only makes sense $\mu_n$-almost surely (where $\mu_n(\cdot)=\mathbf{P}(X_n\in\cdot)$ is the law of $X_n$), and since $\mu_n$ changes as $n$ progresses, comparing this function for different $n$ will only make sense when we introduce a ($\sigma$-fintie) measure $\mu$ with respect to which all the $\mu_n$'s are absolutely continuous. (A quintessential example of this is when all $X_n$'s are discrete.) Even under this, the question kind of asks if we can improve convergence in probability to a.e.-convergence, so I am skeptical about the validity...

Comment: At least we can prove that $(Y_n\mid X_n)$ converges weakly to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in probability, in the sense that $$\forall f\in C_b(\mathbb{R}) \ : \qquad \mathbf{E}[f(Y_n)\mid X_n] \to \mathbf{E}[f(Z)] \quad \text{in probability}$$ where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. (Note that, if there is no conditioning, then this is precisely the definition of $Y_n \to Z$ in distribution by the Portmanteau theorem.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you. This is what I am looking for. If you put this in the answer then I will accept.

Comment: @SangchulLee when you talk about the "quintessential" example you mean that if the Xn are discrete than they have automatically a density right ? And therefore everything is automatically defined? Just for my understanding...

Comment: @Thomas, Indeed. If all $X_n$'s are discrete, and if we choose $\mu$ as the counting measure on the union of the support of $X_n$'s, then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and we can discuss the "density" $$ p_{X_n}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{P}(X_n\in\cdot)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}=\mathbf{P}(X_n=x). $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the topology of convergence in distribution. Also, ​for each $n$, let $\mu_n(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(Y_n \in \cdot \mid X_n)$ denote the regular conditional distribution of $Y_n$ given $X_n$. Note that each $\mu_n$ is a $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$-valued random variable.

Then we claim that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ in probability, in the sense that for each neighborhood $U$ of $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{P}(\mu_n \notin U) = 0. $$

By the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_random_variables), this is equivalent to showing that for each bounded, continuous $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$ \mu_n [f] = \mathbf{E}[f(Y_n) \mid X_n] \to \mathbf{E}[f(Z)] \quad \text{in probability}, $$

where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

---

To this end, write

$$ D_n(g) = \left| \mu_n[g] - \mathbf{E}[g(Z)] \right| \qquad\text{and}\qquad M_n
= \sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}} \left| D_n(\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, z)}) \right|. $$

Then each $M_n$ defines a random variable, and the assumption corresponds to the fact that $M_n \stackrel{p}\to 0$. Also, for each $-\infty \leq a < b \leq +\infty$, we have

\begin{align*}
\mu_n([a, b))
= \mu_n[\mathbf{1}_{[a, b)}]
&\leq D_n(\mathbf{1}_{[a, b)}) + \mathbf{P}(Z \in [a, b)) \\
&\leq D_n(\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, b)}) + D_n(\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, a)}) + \mathbf{P}(Z \in [a, b)) \\
&\leq 2M_n + \mathbf{P}(Z \in [a, b))
\end{align*}

and hence

\begin{align*}
D_n(f \mathbf{1}_{[a, b)})
&\leq \biggl(\sup_{[a, b)} |f| \biggr) \bigl[ \mu_n([a, b)) + \mathbf{P}(Z \in [a, b)) \bigr] \\
&\leq \biggl(\sup_{[a, b)} |f| \biggr) \bigl[ 2M_n + 2\mathbf{P}(Z \in [a, b)) \bigr].
\end{align*}

Now, let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, and choose $\eta, R, \delta > 0$ so that

- $(2+4\sup|f|)\eta < \varepsilon$,
- $\mathbf{P}(Z \geq R) < \eta$, and
- $|f(x) - f(y)| < \eta$ whenever $x, y \in [-R, R]$ and $|x - y| < \delta$,

Also. let $-R = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_N = R$ be such that $|x_{k+1} - x_k| < \delta$. We first bound $D_n(f)$ as

\begin{align*}
D_n(f)
&\leq D_n(f\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, -R)}) + D_n(f\mathbf{1}_{[R, \infty)}) + \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} D_n(f\mathbf{1}_{[x_k, x_{k+1})}).
\end{align*}

Then by noting that

\begin{align*}
&D_n(f\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, -R)}) + D_n(f\mathbf{1}_{[R, \infty)}) \\
&\leq (\sup|f|)(4M_n + 2\mathbf{P}(Z < -R) + 2\mathbf{P}(Z \geq R)) \\
&\leq (\sup|f|)(4M_n + 4\eta)
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} D_n(f\mathbf{1}_{[x_k, x_{k+1})}) \\
&\leq \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} D_n( (f - f(x_k)) \mathbf{1}_{[x_k, x_{k+1})} ) +  \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|f(x_k)| D_n(\mathbf{1}_{[x_k, x_{k+1})}) \\
&\leq \eta \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \bigl[ \mu_n( [x_k, x_{k+1}) ) + \mathbf{P}(Z \in [x_k, x_{k+1})) \bigr] + (\sup |f|) \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} D_n(\mathbf{1}_{[x_k, x_{k+1})}) \\
&\leq  2\eta+ 2 (\sup|f|) N M_n,
\end{align*}

we obtain

$$ D_n(f) \leq (2+4\sup|f|)\eta + (\sup|f|)(2N + 4) M_n. $$

Using this and $M_n \stackrel{p}\to 0$ together, we conclude

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{P}( D_n(f) > \varepsilon) = 0. $$

Since $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, this implies that $D_n(f) \stackrel{p}\to 0$ and therefore the desired conclusion follows.

---

*Remark.* If you look at the proof closely, all we need is to assume that
$$ \mathbf{P}(Y_n < z \mid X_n) \stackrel{p}\to \mathbf{P}(Z < z), \qquad\text{or equivanetly,}\qquad D_n(\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, z)}) \stackrel{p}\to 0 $$
for each $z \in \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure if the (seemingly) stronger assumption $M_n \stackrel{p}\to 0$ leads to a stronger conclusion.

Comment: I would like to understand your answer. Why in the initial formula you want to show that the sequence mu_n belong to the neighborhood with probability zero and not one? Intuitively as far as I understand you want to show kind of a convergence to the normal distribution of which U is a neighborhood?

Comment: @Thomas, Ah, indeed that is a typo. It should be analogous to the definition of convergence in probability for $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables: $$X_n\stackrel{p}\to c \qquad\iff\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{P}(X_n\notin U)=0\quad\text{for any neighborhood $U$ of $c$}$$ Let me fix it :)